# What is another way of saying "unprofessional"?

Tags: british-english

I am marking undergraduate papers and I've been asked by Dep. Head to avoid using the term "unprofessional" to refer to students' reports.

What is another nicer (but accurate) way of saying a report, due to the wrong choice of words or simply syntactical errors, is unprofessional?

Comment: "Sloppy" or "too informal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be specific: "This sentence is awkwardly worded." "This phrasing is ambiguous." "There is a grammatical error here."

You might describe the entire report as "unpolished" or "requiring revision" or "not thoroughly edited", which is polite in that it implies that the student would be capable of turning in a better product if they had more time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an adjective converted from the noun 'dilettante'
: a person having a superficial interest in an art or a branch of knowledge (from: Merriam-Webster Dictionary).